# How to get current URL from Mechanize in Python?

Tags: python, web, authentication, mechanize

I'm trying to login in and get URL from upcoming page :

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
url = "http://www.blahblah.com/login-page/"
br.open( url )

br.select_form(nr = 1)
br.form['username'] = "Foo"
br.form['password'] = "fooPswRd"
br.submit()
```

...so far so good. Now I need an URL from redirected page, any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`br.geturl()` should do it. Using [httpbin.org's](http://httpbin.org) redirect endpoint to test:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
url = 'http://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com'
br.open( url )

>>> print br.geturl()
http://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Should I transfer the cookie with URL into my QT webkit browser? ...what else do I need except URL?